# How to pass multiselect combobox data using uploadify

Tags: php, uploadify

This is my uploadify code:

```
'onUploadStart' : function(){
    $j('#my_file').uploadifySettings('postData',{
    'myCat'    :$j('#myCat').val()
    });
}
```

This is my form with one field:

```
form field:
<select name="myCat" id="myCat" multiple="multiple">
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
<option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
```

This line: 'myCat'    :$j('#myCat').val() only passes the last value I select in my select dropdown box.

How do I pass all the values I select in the "myCat" field?

Comment: Uploadify is all about multiple files. Do you want a separate dropdown for each file, or just one for all files?

Comment: ...of course if you never come back to this website to answer queries, you will not get much help :)